# Use a spfx web part for dynamic filtering of a standard library web part

Tags: spfx, web-part-connection

I'm looking for a way to filter a document library view on a SP Online web part page. There used to be a Query string filter web part which would be ideal for me: I would create a url like products.aspx?q=juicer . Unfortunately this is no longer possible on modern pages.

Since I don't mind doing a bit of scripting, I was wondering if it is at all possible to do this using using [dynamic data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/dynamic-data)
This is being advertised that it can send data between framework web parts, but I was wondering if this could be used to create a web part that sends data to a standard document library web with dynamic filtering enabled.

Comment: Check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/283358/spfx-using-the-oob-filter-on-a-modern-document-library-webpart-using-dynamic-d). Here OP is saying **document library webpart's property pane doesn't pick up the custom web part as an option for filtering**.

Comment: That is pretty much what I am trying to accomplish also and also what I experienced in a test the other day. The custom web part doesn't show up in the list of available web parts for filtering... Maybe there is another way?